# Adding location based AD groups with Powershell that will prompt for input on what location to put

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I currently have a powershell script I am using to add users to certain AD groups and it prompts me to input the username and will then add those groups to that users AD account. What I would like to do is add another prompt within this script to prompt for input for region specific AD groups. For example, I want to add the group (Region) - Admissions, but for Region I want to be prompted to put in the actual region. Below is the script I currently have :

```
"Group - 1","Group - 2" |
Add-ADGroupMember -Members `
    (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter User Name")
```

Ideally I would want it to function and look the exact same but just add on more groups at the top and then the prompt scripts would be below that. Any ideas on how to do this at all? I'm not very good at this type of stuff haha

An example of what the groups would look like are :

```
"Group - 1","Group - 2", "(Region) Admissions", "(Facility) Admissions" |
Add-ADGroupMember -Members `
    (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter User Name")
```

Where `(Region)` and `(Facility)` are what I am wanting it to prompt me for input on that and the input would replace those words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* `Read-Host` to read the values from the user, then use an expandable string or the `-f` operator to add them to a template string:

```
# Ask for variable input form user
$regionName = Read-Host 'Give me a region!'
$facilityName = Read-Host 'Give me a facility!'

# Construct group names based on input
$regionGroupName = "${regionName} Admissions"
$facilityGroupName = "${facilityName} Admissions"

# Define the static group names
$staticGroups = "Group 1", "Group 2"

# Add the group memberships
@(
    $staticGroups
    $regionGroupName
    $facilityGroup
) |Add-ADGroupMember -Members (Read-Host "Input user name")
```

But a better solution might be to *parameterize* these variables:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [string]$RegionName,
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [string]$FacilityName,
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [string]$UserName
)

# Construct group names based on input
$regionGroupName = "${regionName} Admissions"
$facilityGroupName = "${facilityName} Admissions"

# Define the static group names
$staticGroups = "Group 1", "Group 2"

# Add the group memberships
@(
    $staticGroups
    $regionGroupName
    $facilityGroup
) |Add-ADGroupMember -Members $UserName
```

At which point we can start to make PowerShell impose *constraints* on input values:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [ValidateSet("North", "East", "South", "West", "Center")]
  [string]$RegionName,

  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [ValidateSet("HQ", "Satelite", "Mobile")]
  [string]$FacilityName,

  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [string]$UserName
)

# ...
```

Now the user won't accidentally enter a region or facility name that *doesn't* exist :)